# mailx - sending zip files

Tags: unix, scripting, mailx

I have a zip file named : zip_final.zip

I have to attach this file as a attachment and send the mail.

Also, I have to display all the file_names present inside the zip file in the mail body.

I have this code :

```
export files_list=`unzip -Zl zip_final.zip`

mailx -a ${zip_final.zip} -s "Files list | Zip file" << EOM

   Hi team, sent zip file.
   Files inside it are  :  $files_list

   Thank you.

EOM
```

But the mail is not sent if I am doing this. Like the mail command is not even getting called/triggered. I am not even getting any error messages too.

**Can someone suggest how to send that zipfile as an attachment using mailx command and also display all the file names inside the zipfile in the mail body?**

Comment: Which implementation of `mailx` are you using? What does its documentation say the `-a` option is for? How do you know the command is not being run? Why are you not specifying any recipients?

Comment: Duplicate of this [same question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/707798/100397), which already has answers